# Javafx Text and Label fonts are look different

Tags: css, javafx, styles

I'm trying to make my Text object look like other blocks which are using Label to display some text. I cannot use Label because I need the feature of Text to setup wrap width. But I see the straight difference between final displayed text. As you can see from screenshot Text's font is looking little bolder than Label's. How can I style my Text to look just like the Label?

I thought that it is only my stylesheet problem, but I can see the same difference within SceneBuilder.

[Preview inside scenebuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjPpA.png)

Comment: Why not change the `Labels` to `Text`?

Answer (score 3):

In the [default style sheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css), the text color in a label is set to a looked-up color called `-fx-text-background-color` (this *is* the foreground color of the text, despite the name), which in turn depends on the looked-up color `-fx-background` (hence the name...). The value of `-fx-background` is typically inherited from the parent; the idea here is that it uses a color that contrasts with the background. The value is defined as

```css
-fx-text-background-color: ladder(
    -fx-background,
    -fx-light-text-color 45%,
    -fx-dark-text-color  46%,
    -fx-dark-text-color  59%,
    -fx-mid-text-color   60%
);
```

So you can make the text look like a label by using the same CSS looked-up color for the text's `-fx-fill` property. Here is a very quick and dirty demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextColor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label plainLabel = new Label("A plain label");
        Text styledText = new Text("Styled text");
        styledText.setStyle("-fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;");
        Text plainText = new Text("A plain text");

        VBox root = new VBox(10, plainLabel, styledText, plainText);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

which gives

[image]

This also makes the `Text` react appropriately to changes in the background. If you add

```
root.setStyle("-fx-background: black;");
```

then the styled text (and the label, by default) responds:

[image]

Note also that for your use case for `Text`, a combination of

```
label.setPrefWidth(...);
label.setWrapText(true);
```

will enable you to control the wrapping width of a label, and may be a more natural solution to what you are trying to do than the approach you are suggesting here.